# Can I select multiple discontiguous dates at once in fullcalendar resourceTimeline views?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a user requirement to select multiple discontiguous day slots for which we'd create separate events with the same details for a single resource. I was expecting that might work by shift-clicking multiple days.

Is this possible? If so, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: There's no feature in fullCalendar itself to support that no. It's probably possible to do something with your own code which makes it happen, though.